# JQuery Scheduler with drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scheduler

We want to create a customized scheduler in HTML5, CSS3 and JQuery. With the possibility to list items outside of the Scheduler, so that the user can drag the items and drop them inside the Schedule.

Users can not create events inside the Scheduler, they can just drag and drop existing events (that are saved in a database).

We also want to show schedules of user's friends, when the user types the name of a friend in a textbox, so that he can synchronize/organize/discuss his own tasks with the other user.

Is there any jQuery plugin that can do that, and that doesn't give the possibility to create new events inside the scheduler?

I already started to do this from scratch, but I won't be able deliver on time.

Answer (score 1):

look at [fullcalendar.io scheduler](https://fullcalendar.io/scheduler/). The scheduler pat it's triple licensed, free for opensource prj